# I am not able to Install a printer after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing

I am still unable to install the printer (HP Deskjet f2275) which is connected to the Computer via an USB cable and the power is ON
The step I am doing are:

- Go to System Setting
- select Printer then Add (printer)

The display table  Left column is 
    Device
    Enter URI

> Network Printer

I have taken the printer to a friend computer and I was able to install the Printer the difference between My Computer and his Computer is
The display table Left column says:

```
Device
    Serial 1
    Serial 5
    Network Printer
```

Thus by opening the Serial Port 1 
I get a list of Manufacturer of printer which I do not get on my computer.
Please can you tell me how to get the List of Manufactures on my Computer
I will be most greatfullI do not thik

Thank you
Ferruccio
I have notice the following statement in "Printer State":"Stopped - File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups" not available: No such file or directory”
I do not think that CUPS is install( OR corrupt) 
I do I check if CUPS is install and I do re-install CUPS

When I started my PC I had the following error:
    Sorry Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error

```
Executable Path
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cups=pk-helper-mechanism
Package
cups-pk-helper0.2.5-2ubuntu2
ProblemType
Crash 
Title
cups-helper-mechanism crashed with signal 5 in g_variant_new_va()
ApportVersion
2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1
Archtecture
amd64
CrashCounter
1
```

Comment: do you have `HPLIP` drivers installed ?

Comment: How can I find if I have HPLIP driver install. I do not think so. I am steel learning Ubuntu.

Comment: let put down the steps to follow.

Comment: see posted answer let me know how it went.

Comment: Your printer is supported as can be seen here http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_f2200_series.html. To install hplip `sudo apt-get install hplip` However, I am not sure this will solve your problem, as your system does not seem to recognize the other ports. Its worth a try though.

Comment: I have add comment to my original question

Comment: This did not fix my problem. I believe that the pc do not have CUPS , how do I install CUPS

Comment: please use the comments section to respond or communicate with me rather than _editing_ my answer.

Comment: To check if hplip is installed run `dpkg -l hplip` in the terminal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hp has support for certain printers so you can check [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html).

Steps:

- follow the [link](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) provided above
- click on the download HPLIP button
- select the following from the drop down:

  - distribution (in your case ubuntu)
  - version (16.04)
  - printer type (pick your printer type from the list)
  - printer model (your printer model)
- click next

Now if your printer is already supported by your distro (*ubuntu*) then nothing else but if you need the latest *drivers* then **click next** to download it.

if you decided to download latest drivers, simply follow the *online* instructions to install.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry ,but I believed that I was editing my question. I have edited my question I hope. thank you

Comment: Ok but how has gone with the printer issue ?

Comment: My printers now work by installing hplip Note All so CUPS was install.

Comment: so i guess my answer helped, if so please mark as accepted answer. Glad it was resolved.